# Why is this integral bounded?

Tags: integration, analysis, inequality

Someone told me earlier that $$\int_{\delta}^{\infty} u^{\beta} e^{-cu^{2}} du <\infty$$ for positive $\beta$ and $c$.

How could I prove this is true? The only way I can think of to do this is by recognizing it as an incomplete gamma function, but is there any another way?

Comment: Sure: note that there is no singularity at the lower endpoint, then compare it to an integral of $e^{-cu}$ which you can do explicitly. This integrand is eventually smaller than $e^{-cu}$.

Comment: The theme is that exponential decay beats the polynomial growth. A cheap way would be to think about $e^x = 1 + x + \cdots + x^B/B! + \cdots$, where $B = \lfloor \beta/2 \rfloor + 1$, say. So then $e^{cy^2} > c (y^2)^B/B!$, and thus $e^{-cy^2} = 1/e^{cy^2} < 1 / c y^{\beta + 2}$. Thus the integral converges.

Comment: @Ian In fact, using $\log(u)<u$, we can compare to a scaled and shifted version of $e^{-cu^2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the crude estimate $\log(u)<u$, for $u>0$, we see that for $\beta>0$, $c>0$

$$u^\beta e^{-cu^2}=e^{-cu^2+\beta\log(u)}<e^{-c(u-\beta/2c)^2}e^{\beta^2/4c}$$

Hence, we can assert that for any $\delta>0$

$$\int_\delta^\infty u^\beta e^{-cu^2}\,du< e^{\beta^2/4c} \int_{\delta-\beta/2c}^\infty e^{-cu^2}\,du$$

Can you finish now?

Comment: Oh that's slick!

Comment: @Glassjawed Thank you!  Much appreciated.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Comment: This is good for me--I think.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Prove that $x^\beta e^{-cx^2}=o\big(e^{-x}\big)$ as $x\to\infty$ for any $c>0$. Then:
$$\int_\delta^\infty x^\beta e^{-cx^2}\,dx\leq\int_\delta^N x^\beta e^{-cx^2}\,dx+\int_N^\infty e^{-x}\,dx<\infty$$
for some $N$, so the integral converges.